# Wrapping Plugin Code with Jquery On()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, materialize

It's been a while since I used jquery, the last time I used query .live was still a thing.

Now I see it's been replaced with "On" ( I personally don't like this name it makes it hard to google for answers)

I am using MaterialzieCss and their modal dialog `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();`

However I want to load the modal code on demand(ie when something clicks on a link it does an ajax call and grabs the html for the dialog and then display it to the user).

How do I wrap  `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();` in the "on" so it get bound when it finds the modal code?

Before there use to be some jquery plugin that did that since "live" was unable to do it. Is this still the case?

Edit

Here is some code maybe it will make it a bit clearer.

Current

```
<body>
<a class="modal-trigger" data-target="add-modal">Open Modal </a>
<div id="add-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Hi</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat left">Add</a>
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{ 
     $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
}
</script>
</body>
```

Now I want to remove the "#add-modal" to be on demand. When you click the link that "modal" code would be added to the body.

Maybe I am not clear from the solutions provided but by calling `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();` each time would create new bindings? I going to have like 5 modals so won't calling each time keep adding so at one point if I click on my link it would open like 5 modals of the same thing?

Comment: `on()` isn't what you need here. Instead you should simply call `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal()` *inside* the callback function of the AJAX requests which add the `.modal-trigger` element to the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonid', function(e) {
    $.get('/getmodalcode')
     .done(function(data){
         $('#outputid').append(data);
         $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
     });
});
```

Hope it is clear enough and I've interpreted correctly your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(data) {
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  });
```

`data` is, you guessed it, the data that is returned. So if you want to use that data as HTML input for the modal, do something like this.

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(data) {
    $('.modal-trigger').html(data).leanModal();
  });
```

You are right that in some cases `.on()` is preferred. The most important use case is when directing bubbling events of dynamically added elements. For instance, if `#container` is a static element, and `.element` was dynamically added, the will not work because at the time the script first ran, that element was not present yet and the event handler was not attached.

```
$(".element").click(function() {
  // Do something
});
```

Instead, assign the click handler to the container, but delegate the event down.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".element", function() {
  // Do something
});
```

So, putting everything together: if you want to run an ajax call by clicking a link that has been dynamically added, and on a successful can pop the modal:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".link", function() {
  $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function(data) {
      $('.modal-trigger').html(data).leanModal();
    });
});
```